# Independent linear forms

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume one has $m+1$ independent linear forms $L_0,\dots,L_m$ in $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^{m+1},\mathbb R)$. Consider a non zero linear form $L\in\mathcal L(\mathbb R^{m+1},\mathbb R)$. It must be very easy, but I do not see why one can choose $m$ linear forms $L_{i1},\dots,L_{i_m}$ in the set $L_0,\dots,L_m$ such that the forms $L_{i1},\dots,L_{i_m},L$ are linear independent.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the dimension of $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^{m+1},\mathbb R)$ equals $m+1$. Knowing this you may apply the [exchange lemma of Steinitz](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma)

Comment: Thanks. I did not remember this lemma.